# Making dynamic form inputs with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to update the nested fields in react forms .,

here i do

add a new item `handleAddShareholder` ,

delete an existing item `handleRemoveShareholder`,

change details of an item `handleShareholderNameChange`

then i will push a new array to shareholders.customize by this

```
handleAddcomp = idx => () => {
    this.state.shareholders[idx].customize.push({ name: '' });
    const shareholders = this.state.shareholders;
    this.setState({ shareholders: shareholders });
  };
```

but i can't able to update the field value of nested arrays in react.js

my code is here https://jsbin.com/fugemuy/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Not really clear what you want to do, and what's happening when you do it.

Comment: I want to update sub share holder input which was nesting  inside sharesholder

Comment: Updating the subholder was not getting as desired ., did u look my jsbin .can u plz say a way to do

Comment: So, ok. I see your problem. I had similar problem before, if you want this component to update separately, it needs it's own state. I have a question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421150/dynamically-created-elements-in-react-how-to-have-control Please, look at it, and see how you can apply it to your own situation

Comment: Okay let me check .,

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for this purpose. It will clone current object.

```
handleAddcomp = idx => () => {
    let shareholders = Object.assign({}, this.state.shareholders); //creating copy of object in state
    shareholders[idx].customize.push({ name: '' })
    this.setState({ shareholders });
};
```